# How can identical binaries have different performance?

Tags: performance

I've been writing a small C program on Linux that mmaps a large file and parses it. I've been testing it on a GCP instance. The instance is just a single NUMA node (at least that's what numactl --hardware says).

Sometimes the system will get into a state where certain binaries suddenly become about 10% faster or slower. This difference will be persistent across all runs and is well outside the variance between runs.

The unexplainable thing is that it's specific to the binary. I can have an identical binary (verified with diff) that is ~10% faster or slower. I can rename the binaries to whatever, including swapping names, but they appear to maintain some hidden provenance that controls their performance.

When making a copy of the binary it's unclear exactly what is happening. The resulting binary's performance doesn't seem related to the original, but is instead fixed at a new value in the +/- 10% performance range.

Flushing the system page cache doesn't have an effect. Restarting the compute instance usually resolves it, but not always.

I feel like I'm going crazy. I can't think of any explanation for this behavior.

**Edit:**
I don't have a physical machine to test this on. I would think that stopping and starting the instance would reschedule it to a different machine, but I'm not sure how to verify.

I believe it's CPU-bound. Looking at the specs for the Zen2 CPU the CCD has a read bandwidth of 72GB/s and my code is processing around 24GB/s.

To be clear this behavior is tied to the *binary* and not the file that is being read. The file being read is around ~15GB, the binary is 32KB.

I'm not sure how to test the effects of different memory speed/latency. A physical memory issue possibly explains it getting slower, but not faster.

Possibly the physical address the binary is loaded at is affecting addressing in the L1 instruction cache?

Or maybe something could be happening with the kernel and virtual memory? The time difference is roughly the time spent by the kernel handling page faults in the memory mapped file.

Comment: Does the same thing happen when you request an entirely new GCP instance? Could be something as obscure as a memory stick with some slight issues (that requires re-transmission of detected faults) ... Can you reproduce this variance on a physical machien or only on GCP? Is your task CPU-bound or IO-bound? How much does memory speed/latency affect it?

Comment: I added some more details

Comment: My first guess would be that one of the files is fragmented on disk, but (1) that only affects initial loading time, and (2) doesn't explain why it goes away on reboot.

Comment: I've had a similar weird issue: I'm benchmarking an executable on an ARM Linux GCP instance. If I build it twice and time ~1000 runs of each executable, there is often a small, but statistically significant) mean execution time difference (~0.5%). The executable hashes match (they wouldn't normally, but I'm testing the benchmark harness itself) and the runs are interleaved. The subprocesses time themselves (so startup time is excluded). I can't reproduce the issue on x86 Linux GCP, or on a Mac. My only working solution is to make a new copy of the binary for each iteration of the benchmark.